# C++ How to use substring in a text file

Tags: c++, substring

ive created a function that is designed to read numbers contained in a text file, convert them to int using an atoi function and then use them in their new int format to do simple calculations. This is the function I have written

```
double robotComplexity() {

std:string output = outputFile;
std::string input = output.substr(13,2);

double complexity = 20 * atoi(input.c_str());

   if(complexity > 100) {
      complexity = 100;
   }

cout << complexity << endl;
return complexity;
}
```

And this is the file that another function reads, and then from this the function robotComplexity can calculate the complexity of the robot. The substring paramaters (13,2) refers to the 13th element, being 7, then the 2 refers to the size(thus the subtring retrives 70)

```
Reliable Rover:70:1.
Sloppy Simon:20:4.
Technical Tom:90:3.
A:Head:1:2:15.
B:Torso:0:6:5.
C:Leg:0:4:6.
D:Arm:0:4:8.
E:Tail:0:6:2.
Carly:Cat:ABCCCCE.
Dodgy Dan:Dog:BCACECC.
Ernie:Ettin:AABCCDD.
Sally:Snake:AEEEEEE.
```

However, when i run the program it doesnt operate properly and i recieve the error 
"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 13) > this->size() (which is 10)"

this is the complete program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "driver.h"
#include "implementation.cpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {

readFile(inputFile1, inputFile2, inputFile3, lines);
writeFile(outputFile, lines);
robotComplexity();
getch();
return 0;

}

void Customer() {
std::string customerName;
std::string projectName;
std::string partNumber;;
}

void Parts() {

char partCode;
std::string partName;
int maximum;
int minimum;
int complexity;

}
void Builder() {

std:string name;
int ability;
int variability;

}

//second file
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string inputFile1 = "Builders.txt";
std::string inputFile2 = "Parts.txt";
std::string inputFile3 = "Customers.txt";
std::string outputFile = "output.txt";
std::string input;

void readFile(std::string const& inputFile1, std::string const& inputFile2, std::string const& inputFile3,
              std::vector<std::string>& lines) //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{
   std::ifstream file1(inputFile1);
   std::ifstream file2(inputFile2);
   std::ifstream file3(inputFile3);
   std::string line;

   while(std::getline(file1, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
   }

     while(std::getline(file2, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
   }

     while(std::getline(file3, line)) 
   {
      lines.push_back(line);
   }

   for(std::string print: lines) { //prints the list that was written to

     std::cout << print << std::endl;
}
}


double robotComplexity() {

std:string output = outputFile;
std::string input = output.substr(14,1);

double complexity = 20 * atoi(input.c_str());


   if(complexity > 100) {
      complexity = 100;
   }

cout << complexity << endl;
return complexity;
}

double robotVariability(double variability) {

return variability;
}

void writeFile(std::string const& outputFile,
               std::vector<std::string> const& lines) //writes to a file output.txt the end calculations. 
{
   std::ofstream file(outputFile);
   for(std::string const& line: lines)
   {
      file << line << std::endl;
   }

}
```

When working the program should calculate 20 * 70, which is greater than 100 thus it returns 100. 
thankyou for the help!

Comment: While you haven't shown the code that reads a string from the file into the variable named `outputFile`, I can imagine that you might be trying to read a string using `someFileStream >> outputFile`, which of course would stop reading characters when it hits whitespace.  Consider using `std::getline` to read a whole line.  Also, range-test before substr or handle exceptions.  Also, use a debugger or [various other debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to easily find the cause of problems like this.

Comment: are you sure you counted right? "Reliable Rover:" == 15 chars, try instead to search for delimiters in the text using find then use what is returned to extract from the string.

Comment: @paddy I am using getline

Comment: Have you tried looking at the contents of the string variable `output` just prior to the exception being thrown?

Comment: @paddy that seems to be fine, i believe the issue is what AndersK sugguested. When im a bit rusty with substring. For what im trying to achieve, would 7 be the 13th element of the list?

Comment: Indexing starts at 0.  So 13 is the 14th character in the string.  Just count.  I highly recommend using `std::string::find` to locate the `:`.  Or put it into a `std::istringstream` and use `std::getline` on that, supplying `:` as the delimiter character.

Comment: @paddy I have included the readfile function

Comment: @paddy does the characters include both the blank space and the :?

Comment: Your updated code example is even more perplexing.  It does not call `robotComplexity`, nor does it show how the (presumably) global string variable `outputFile` is used.  I don't understand your last comment.  A character can be a letter, digit, punctuation, space, control value, etc...  whatever.

Comment: @paddy ive updated to include the full code.

Comment: @paddy Ive included the full text file, my apologies I thought i copied the whole file and not just the first line.

Comment: That is not a complete program.  There is no `main`, and it contains basic syntax errors that will cause it not to compile.  Furthermore, the function `robotComplexity` is not being called anywhere.  You seem to have ignored just about everything I've said.  Especially the bit where I asked you if you had examined the ACTUAL value of `outputFile`.  I think what you did is just make an assumption about its value.  Assumptions get you nowhere, when you are debugging.

Comment: main has been included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
As you included the whole program, you're assigning `output` to the string "output.txt", which has size 10 and index 14 is out of range.

As a side note, if you have C++11, it's easier to just use std::stoi(input) to parse the string.

Comment: Ive tried using inde13-16 and the output is still the same

Comment: also ive included the full output.txt file, my apologies i thought i included the full file and not just the first line.

Comment: At line `std:string output = outputFile;`, you're assigning the variable `output` with another string `outputFile` which has value "output.txt". Now, you're actually doing `"output.txt".substr(14,1)`, which clearly is out out bounds.

Comment: so you're saying its not equal to the context of the file, rather its equal to its name, output.txt?

Comment: Yes, it's just copy assignment now. `outputFile` is of type std::string. Aren't you supposed to use `readFile` to get the content of the file?

Comment: Yea I've already done that. So in my robotComplexity function whats the proper assignment for variable output so that it is equal to the context of the output file?

Comment: What do you mean by "context of the output file"?  Don't you simply want to pass in one of the strings from your `lines` array?

Comment: output.txt is a file that i have included in this question. Im trying to read part of the first line using substring.

Comment: meant to say content not context

Comment: And when do you want to do that, given that your program never calls this function?

Comment: You can use, e.g. `std::string output = lines[0];` to parse the first line of the file.

Comment: @paddy I have included main which calls the functions

Comment: @R-penguins and thankyou this is what I've been wanting.